# Compiling error - Kernel source for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a Linux kernel version rpi-4.14 for Raspberry Pi on Linux system.
The build is done with cross compiler arm-linux-gnueabihf with the configuration bcm2709_defconfig.
I'm running the command:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage modules dtbs
```

But I get the following error:

```
arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/midi-uart0-overlay.dts:4:39: fatal error: dt-bindings/clock/bcm2835.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.lib:328: recipe for target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/midi-uart0.dtbo' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/midi-uart0.dtbo] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:587: recipe for target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays] Error 2
arch/arm/Makefile:350: recipe for target 'dtbs' failed
make: *** [dtbs] Error 2
```

The file dt-bindings/clock/bcm2835.h is in place, so I do not really know what the problem is.

Comment: I'm facing the same, the file is present. Did you fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is a file missing.

```
arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/midi-uart0-overlay.dts:4:39: fatal error: dt-bindings/clock/bcm2835.h: No such file or directory
```

Check if the directory exists, look for the file you need and change the directory in the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an erroneous symbolic link under `arch/arm/boot/dts/include`. The kernel sources have been packed/unpacked by 7z, maybe that was an issue.

Solved it via 
`ln -s ~/kernel-building/linux-raspberrypi-kernel_1.20170703-2/include/dt-bindings arch/arm/boot/dts/include/dt-bindings`

Trying to link in relative to the current directory did not work.